# How to change css via Jquery on dynamically created element before adding to document DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this dynamically created Element, created via 3rd party lib (jsondiffpatch.formatters.html.format()).

I want to do some css and content changes on it before adding to document DOM.

I tried doing this but failed:

```
function transformDelta(deltaHtml: any) {
  $(deltaHtml)
    .find(".jsondiffpatch-delta > ul > li")
    .each(function () {
      console.log($(this).text());
    });
  return deltaHtml;
}
```

How is this done?

Additional codes:

Button to display the json changes

```
<ChangesModalButton
  variant="primary"
  getMatrixDelta={() => {
    const delta = diffpatcher.diff(orig, cur);
    const deltaHtml = jsondiffpatch.formatters.html.format(delta);
    const Container = (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: deltaHtml }} />
      );
    return Container;
  }}
/>
```

The Button definition that displays the modal

```
export function ChangesModalButton(props: any) {
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);
  const [matrixDelta, setMatrixDelta] = React.useState<any>(null);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChangesModal
        matrixDelta={matrixDelta}
      />

      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setMatrixDelta(props.getMatrixDelta());
          setModalShow(true);
        }}
      >
        <img src={seeChangesMatrixImg} alt="" />
      </Button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Modal definition

```
class ChangesModal extends Component<any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
      >
        <Modal.Body>{this.props.matrixDelta? this.props.matrixDelta: "No Changes"}</Modal.Body>           
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling this transformDelta after that element is placed in DOM?? Can you please share code. We can't determine from what you posted in question.

Comment: @maverickosama92 added codes

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you can't do css changes until dom is rendered.
After Dom is rendered you can do css changes.

If you are going to change an elemenet color in css let say element is p1 then

```
 $(p1).css('color','blue');
 $('#myId').css('color','blue');//to target id let say Id : myId
 $('.myClass').css('color','blue');//to target class let say css: myClass
```

Or to change its content

```
 $(p1).html("this is new text added dynamically with JQuery");
 $('#myId').html("this is new text added dynamically with JQuery");//to target id let say Id : myId
 $('.myClass').html("this is new text added dynamically with JQuery");//to target class let say css: myClass
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the css method https://api.jquery.com/css/ as follows

```
function transformDelta(deltaHtml: any) {
  $(deltaHtml)
    .find(".jsondiffpatch-delta > ul > li")
    .each(function () {
      $(this).css({"color": "red"})
      console.log($(this).text());
    });
  return deltaHtml;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do that, I tried logging it first just to see if it goes in that part of code. unfortunately, it did not